# Execution of local variables initialized inside logical blocks at run time?

Tags: java, variables, local-variables

Why initialization of local variables inside logical blocks like if-else may or may not execute at run time in java? For ex see below code:

```
 class Test
 {
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    int x;
    if(args.length>0)
    {
        x=10;
    }
    System.out.print(x);
  }
}
```

If i simply compile using **javac Test.java** it shows compile time error and on passing any command line argument it  print 10 as ouutput.

Comment: Can you show a specific code sample you are asking about?

Comment: Could you be more precise please? Maybe provide an example for execution at runtime and another one for the opposite situation. It is not clear to me what you are asking...

Comment: Do you mean if it never enters the blocks?

Comment: Are you sure that the compiler gives you an error? How could you execute it afterwards? Could it be a warning about a possibly non initialized variable? Consider `args.length == 0`, what would be printed in `System.out.println(x)`?

Comment: @deHaar Nope, it's a compiler error, not a warning: https://ideone.com/Z15GSA

Comment: @daniu OK, good... it is about the uninitialized variable. Should be a compilation error anyway.

Comment: @deHaar In case of **args.length==0** it works and output =10

Comment: @ShubhamRai interesting... I have to check that myself! In eclipse, it directly shows an error and refuses to compile...

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that for an empty argument list, `x` will not be initialized before `System.out.print(x)` is executed.

Local variables are not initialized with a default value, contrary to member variables; before `x = 10`, its value is undefined and you cannot access the variable. You can declare it as `int x = 0`, giving it a default value yourself.

Comment: Further reading: [JLS 14.12.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.3).7 and [JLS 14.12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5)